# How do I generate cryptographically random numbers on OSX?

Tags: security, bash, encryption

I need to generate several cryptographically random numbers in OSX and save it to a text file.

How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 6):

The `/dev/random` file on [OS X is fairly good](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator) since it uses the [Yarrow algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yarrow_algorithm) which many consider to be fairly secure in generating random numbers.

You can use dd to pull a character at a time off the stream and as long as you use caution in converting it into a number range you care to see in your text file, this is a fairly painless way to get some decent randomness.

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=1 2>/dev/null >> /path/to/your/file
```